# Javascript & regular expression

Tags: javascript

I have this string

```
java=10514;js=237;jsp=3995;web=5;xml=42
```

and I'd like to extract, in separate variables, the value numbers for each language, using javascript and a regular expression that is, for the "java" case, the follow

```
(?<=java=).*?(?=;|$)
```

I've tried this code

```
var myString = "java=10514;js=237;jsp=3995;web=5;xml=42";
var regexp_java = new RegExp('(?<=java=).*?(?=;|$)', 'g');    
var ncloc_java = sonar_myString.match(regexp_java);
var regexp_js = new RegExp('(?<=js=).*?(?=;|$)', 'g');    
var ncloc_js = sonar_myString.match(regexp_js);
var regexp_jsp = new RegExp('(?<=jsp=).*?(?=;|$)', 'g');    
var ncloc_jsp = sonar_myString.match(regexp_jsp);
var regexp_web = new RegExp('(?<=web=).*?(?=;|$)', 'g');    
var ncloc_web = sonar_myString.match(regexp_web);
var regexp_jsp = new RegExp('(?<=jsp=).*?(?=;|$)', 'g');    
var ncloc_jsp = sonar_myString.match(regexp_jsp);
```

but it doesn't work.

Any suggestion will be appreciated and thank you in advance

Comment: What does not work? What error do you get?

Comment: Any reason it **has** to be regex, rather than simple string manipulation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that you are using the wrong data structure here.  Rather than trying to use individual variables for each language, you can instead use a hashmap.  First split to the string on semicolon, and then stream that to get each language and value.

```js
var input = "java=10514;js=237;jsp=3995;web=5;xml=42";
var map = {};
input.split(";").forEach(x => map[x.split("=")[0]] = x.split("=")[1]);
console.log(map);
```

Comment: Hi there, all is well? Do you agree with the duplicate here?

Comment: @Thefourthbird As a matter of fact, no, I don't.  That duplicate doesn't really cover this question.

Answer (score 2):

Does it really need to be done with Regex? Anyways I'm providing you with 2 solutions.

```js
const string = "java=10514;js=237;jsp=3995;web=5;xml=42";

let result1 = string.split(';').reduce((acc, curr) => {
  let [key, value] = curr.split('=');
  acc[key] = value;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result1);

let result2 = {};
let regex = /([a-z]+)\s*=\s*(\d+)/g;
let check;

while (check= regex.exec(string)) {
  result2[check[1]] = check[2];
}

console.log(result2);
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to create separate patterns and variables, Instead you can use 2 capture groups and then create an object with keys and values (assuming there are no duplicate keys)

```
\b(java|jsp?|web|xml)=([^;\s]+)
```

**Explanation**

- `\b` A word boundary
- `(java|jsp?|web|xml)` Match one of the alternatives
- `=` Match literally
- `([^;\s]+)` Capture group 2, match 1+ chars other than a whitespace char or `;`

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bv8xs4/1).

```js
const myString = "java=10514;js=237;jsp=3995;web=5;xml=42";
const regex = /\b(java|jsp?|web|xml)=([^;\s]+)/g;
const kv = Object.fromEntries(
  Array.from(
    myString.matchAll(regex), m => [m[1], m[2]]
  )
)
console.log(kv)
console.log(kv.java);
```

Comment: Hey buddy, nice code. Could you please explain it from `Object.fromEntries` to its completion. Trying to learn JS but not able to fully understand it. I get that you are doing it in 2 capturing groups and putting output into key value pair format but how its working inside JS thing not sure. Will be grateful to you, Thank you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Hey man, yes of course. The [Object.fromEntries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) `transforms a list of key-value pairs into an object` The [Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) `creates a new, shallow-copied Array instance from an iterable or array-like object.`

Comment: The [String.prototype.matchAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll) `method returns an iterator of all results matching a string against a regular expression, including capturing groups.` 

So `matchall` returns the iterator with the 2 capture group values to `Array.from`, which returns an array of arrays which looks like `[["java","10514"],["js","237"]]` That is a datastructure that Object.fromEntries can process to create an object with key-value pairs.

Comment: Thank you buddy, let me process these comments, thank you for detailed explanation, let us keep these for future users if you ok with it, cheers ++

Comment: Hey, one more question could you please do explain more on `m => [m[1], m[2]]` code? I am not that expert in JS so need to completely understand it, thank you buddy for your help cheers.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 This whole part `m => [m[1], m[2]]` is a function that is passed as the second parameter to `Array.from()` as the inline mapping function. The outer square brackets here `[...]` create an array that will hold the 2 values, where `m[1]`is the capture group 1 value, and `m[2]` the capture group 2 value. So we are basically mapping each item of result from matchAll to an array of array's (where each inner array has 2 values)